# Pls explain php code return ($h & 0x0F) << 12 | (ord($c{1}) & 0x3F) << 6 | (ord($c{2}) & 0x3F);

Tags: php, unicode

I need to understand this php function below

```
function uniord($c) {
    $h = ord($c{0});
    if ($h <= 0x7F) {
        return $h;
    } else if ($h < 0xC2) {
        return false;
    } else if ($h <= 0xDF) {
        return ($h & 0x1F) << 6 | (ord($c{1}) & 0x3F);
    } else if ($h <= 0xEF) {
        return ($h & 0x0F) << 12 | (ord($c{1}) & 0x3F) << 6
                                 | (ord($c{2}) & 0x3F);
    } else if ($h <= 0xF4) {
        return ($h & 0x0F) << 18 | (ord($c{1}) & 0x3F) << 12
                                 | (ord($c{2}) & 0x3F) << 6
                                 | (ord($c{3}) & 0x3F);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have no idea about this:

```
return ($h & 0x1F) << 6 | (ord($c{1}) & 0x3F);
```

what is & << and |

Thanks

Comment: It invalidly decodes UTF-8.

Comment: The symbols are PHP's [bitwise operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

```
&  And           Bits that are set in both $a and $b are set.
|  Or            Bits that are set in either $a or $b are set.
<< Shift left    Shift the bits x steps to the left
```